# What tool is the Google team now promoting for me to test an Angular JS <> Web API application?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Application that uses AngularJS on the front-end, talking to a ASP.NET Web API which then connects through dbContext to a SQL Server 2012 database.

I am not familiar with testing at all and would appreciate if anyone could tell me what method is now being promoted by the Google team for doing testing. Any information on where to start would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS team has built [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) and it is their recommended tool for [end-to-end testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing). For regular [unit testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing), there's [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html).